# Is it possible to detect changes to ng-model in a directive without a deep $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a directive with custom validation logic to validate an object.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="obj" ng-model="vm.obj" validate-object />
```

JS:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('validateObject', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        ngModelCtrl.$validators.validateObject = myValidator;

        function myValidator (modelValue, viewValue) {
          return validateObject(modelValue);
        }

        function validateObject (obj) {
          // Look inside the object
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

The problem is that the validator doesn't run when a property inside the object is changed.

I could add a `$watch` with `objectEquality === true`, and then manually `$setCustomValidity` with my validation logic. Something like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
  scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, onModelChange, true);

  function onModelChange (newValue) {
    ngModelCtrl.$setCustomValidity('validateObject', validateObject(newValue))
  }

  function validateObject (obj) {
    // Look inside the object
  }
}
```

But I don't like using the old school way of manually using `$setValidity`, plus adding a manual `$watch` while `NgModelController` already has ways of registering inside the update process (like `$formatters`), and in addition the `$watch` being a deep one which can has performance issues.

Am I getting this wrong? Is there a better way?

Comment: Why are binding ng-model to an whole obj? The ng-model shoul be bound to an object property

Comment: I dont see any problem in your code here is a working fiddle. Whenever i cahnge the model the validate gets called http://plnkr.co/edit/CqK6WeT6DSMBXwih4Cbu?p=preview

Comment: @Cyril There is nothing wrong with the code. The question is if this is the best way to do it. Deep $watch on an object can have performance issues.

Comment: @slotomo OP says *validator doesn't run when a property inside the object is changed*... but i found nothing wrong..

Comment: @Cyril Sorry. You are right.

Comment: @Cyril Your validator runs since you're binding to a string.

Comment: @Nir In my case I need to look inside an object in order to know if its valid. It doesn't make sense to check only one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L699 :

```
if (ctrl.$$lastCommittedViewValue === viewValue && (viewValue !== '' || !ctrl.$$hasNativeValidators)) {
  return;
}
```

ngModel performs a flat equality check against the older version of the model, so any changes inside an object would not be reflected on ngModel or ngChange.

The perferred approach would be to use immutable data, that means that every time you change the model (the object), create a new copy instead:

```
function changeModel(){
  this.vm.name = "roy";
  // Create a new object for ngModel;
  this.vm = angular.copy(this.vm);
}
```

**EDIT**

I remember that I solved a previous issue before. You want to have a set of ng-models binded to properties on an object, and have 1 change listener for the entire object.

Here's my solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/6tPMrB8n1agINMo252F2?p=preview

What I did was to create a new directive "formModel" that must be placed on a form element. Angular has a form directive which has a controller.
NgModelController requires a parent form controller, which then it adds itself to the form (this is how you get validity on an entire form).
So in my directive, I decorated the form's $addControl method, and added a listener for every ngModelController that adds itself via $viewChangeListeners, and now on every change of ngModel inside the form, the formModel directive will duplicate the entire object and fire $setViewValue.

Comment: Thats a nice original idea but not really practical since I now need to change non-related sections of my code in order to perform the validation.

Comment: Where does the model change occur?

Comment: That's a great pattern! Thanks for sharing. I'm wondering whether using `angular.copy` is more performant than the deep $watch (most likely).
Another issue I see is if you want to observe several objects this way - you'll have a problem since it's defined on the form. I created a slightly different version (before your last one) that shows what I want, even though yours is better with the copy being inside the directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/5cEOwLHn7rJQ60Otm6IZ?p=preview

Comment: The problem with watch is that it fires every time a digest loop occurs, while $viewChangeListeners are fired directly from a ngModel change event.

I guess you can optimize the copy command by creating a shallow copy:
var original = { a: {...}, b: {...}, c: {...} };
var copy = { a: original.a, b: original.b, c: original.c}

Oh, and check my plunkr again, I updated the code to be work with ng-model

Comment: Isn't the ngModel change event fires in a digest loop too? It may be almost the same thing in the end (however indeed its cleaner this way).
I think last time I saw it the ng-model was there already. Wdyt about the issue of multiple objects you want to observe?